# Textarea losing focus after selection in android cordova app

Tags: html, css, cordova, bootstrap-4

Textarea is as following:-

```
<textarea class="" style="border-radius: 0px;border-color: #000 !important;width: 100%;" rows="5" id="gitMessage" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
```

Now when I click on it,soft-keyboard pops-up and it is automatically hidden and textarea also loses focus.

Is there any way in which I can gain focus of textarea and show soft keyboard on clicking inside textarea?

Comment: Wouldn't need to tag javascript here.

Comment: If the textarea loses focus, where does any text that you type get displayed?

Comment: Textarea is not able to gain focus. Everytime it tries to gain focus, it loses it.

Comment: So you can't even focus on the textarea in the first place? Are there other text boxes or input elements on the page? Can they take focus?

Comment: input elements and dropdown are able to take focus. only issue is with textarea.